# Storing a file on Hadoop when not all of its replicas can be stored on the cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, replication

Can somebody let me know what will happen if my Hadoop cluster (replication factor = 3) is only left with 15GB of space and I try to save a file which is 6GB in size?

```
hdfs dfs -put 6gbfile.txt /some/path/on/hadoop
```

Will the `put` operation fail giving error(probably cluster full) or will it save two replicas of the 6GB file and mark the blocks which it cannot save on the cluster as under-replicated and thereby occupying the whole of 15GB of leftover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to store the file.

It will try and accommodate as many replicas as possible. When it fails to store all the replicas, it will throw a warning but not fail. As a result, you will land up with under-replicated blocks.

The warning that you would see is

```
WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Not able to place enough replicas
```

Answer (score 2):

When ever you fire the put command :

dfs utility is behaving like a client here .

client will contact namenode first , then namenode will guide client, where to write the blocks and will keep the maintain metadata for that file , then its client responsibility to break data in block as per configuration specified.

Then client will then make a direct connection with different data nodes , where it has to write different blocks as per namenode reply.

First copy of data would be written by client only on data nodes ,subsequent copies data node will create on each other with the guidance from namenode .

So you should be able to put the file of 6 gb if 15 gb space is there ,because initially the original copies gets created on hadoop , later on once the replication process will start then problem would get arise.